# How to get email address by order id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, orders, email, sales-order

I have a controller that load order like this:

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
```

Is there a way to get a customer e-mail address by load order by id like this?

Comment: Is your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this :

```
$order = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);
$email = $order->getCustomerEmail();
```

To get Customer Id :

```
$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();
```

Comment: You should use DI for that instead of using the object manager directly

Comment: You can inject Order Class Model in your controller __construct method and call in execute method.

Answer (score 2):

Get `Customer Id` from order details and load your customer and you can get `Customer Email`.

**UPDATE:**

`$order = $this->_objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($id);`

`$customerId = $order->getCustomerId();`

Comment: how to get the customer id and then the customer email?